# Removing first blank page

Tags: blank-page, page

I am trying to get rid of the blank page that appears before the title page. I tried this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{ragged2e}  
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{afterpage}   
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}   
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8289}{}  
\begin{document}    
    \justify  
\title{text}  
\author{text}  
\date{}  
\maketitle  
\tableofcontents  
\newpage  
\section{text} 
\end{document}
```

I have tried all the suggestions available on internet including tex.stackexchange. But nothing's working for me.

Comment: remove the \justify command. And while you are one it, replace utf8x by utf8, probably you can actually remove inputenc, in newer latex utf8 is the default.

Comment: What is that justify command suppose to do? Additionally use utf8 not utf8x

Comment: There are almost no places where you ever need to use `\justify` justification is the default.

Comment: I used \justify to align paragraphs throughout the whole article

Comment: paragraphs are justified by default, the only thing `\justify` is doing there is forcing a blank page.

Comment: thanks @DavidCarlisle . I removed \justify and it worked. I've spent almost 1.5 days to fix this issue. But nothing solved it.

Comment: one more thing.. how to write that grey background word in here? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: for inline a single backtick `like this`  marked up   `\`like this\`` for a block like your document example either three backticks at start and end, or use the `{}` button which indents by four spaces which does the same, I just did your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `ragged2e` provides the *environment* `justify`, which should be used as

```
\begin{justify}
...
\end{justify}
```

within a left- or right-flushed text. Like all environments, internally it is implemented by two macros `\justify` and `\endjustify`, which explains why using `\justify` in your example does not lead to obvious (La)TeX errors but to a messed output.

The *switch* you might be interested in is `\justifying`, and using it in your code in place of `\justify` wouldn't produce any empty page. However, as others have pointed out in comments, justified text is the default, so you can remove the macro altogether.